# jQueryUI Sortable - Unable to drag large elements to the top or bottom if containment and handle set

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

For the problem I'm trying to solve, I have a table with unique content for each row.  The rows are allowed to be reordered via a handle, and the content of each row is not always of uniform height.  Sometimes large amounts of text and / or images appear within a row.

There can also be multiple tables with rows that can be reordered, so I'm using the containment property to prevent dragging into other zones and other problematic issues that occur when dragging outside the desired area.

The problem is when I attempt to drag a "tall" row to the top or bottom of the order when the top and bottom are "short" by comparison.  Essentially I am not allowed to drag tall rows to the these positions.  I have searched for a solution and have come up short.  Any help would be appreciated.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffvoigt/XyPzf/

Neither of the two middle rows can be dragged to the top or bottom of the list.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<table id="sortable">
  <tr class="odd">
    <td><p>[=]</p></td>
    <td>Single Line of Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td><p>[=]</p></td>
    <td>Aenean porta, tellus quis auctor elementum, risus ante ornare augue, eu elementum nunc libero ut nisi. Pellentesque sed vestibulum tellus. Proin convallis enim eget felis iaculis viverra vestibulum lorem semper. Aliquam imperdiet viverra lorem, ut dignissim felis laoreet vel. Suspendisse fermentum neque eu est vestibulum bibendum. Maecenas dignissim egestas tempor. Ut tincidunt metus sed felis ornare nec sollicitudin risus gravida. Duis vitae mauris quis risus ultricies malesuada. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus fringilla, arcu eget congue sollicitudin, lorem elit ullamcorper ante, non fermentum orci mauris at tellus. Maecenas suscipit sodales molestie. Mauris luctus porta dui non volutpat.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td><p>[=]</p></td>
    <td><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td><p>[=]</p></td>
    <td>Single Line of Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( "#sortable tbody" ).sortable({
  axis: "y",
  containment: ".container",
  cursor: "move",
  handle: "p"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. This is the quick solution:

```
 $('.collections').sortable({
  handle: 'h3',
  axis: 'y',
  containment: 'parent',
  items: '.collection',
  cursor: 'move',
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  scroll: true,
  beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
    var lastElemTop = $('.collections .collection:last-child').position().top;
    var currElemTop = ui.position.top;
    var currElemHeight = ui.item.height();
    if (currElemTop + currElemHeight * 2 > lastElemTop) {
      $('.collections .collection:last-child').insertBefore(ui.item);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `tolerance: pointer;` is what solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the placement of your handle determines the Y position of the sort in relation to the handle it is on top of. So, to demonstrate, go to jsFiddle and add a valign=top to your big text area. The handle moves to the top of the sortable element, and when you drag it to the top where the short line of text is it will snap into place, but you cannot get it to sort to the bottom. However, if you update the fiddle to be valign=bottom, you may snap it to the bottom but not the top.

Solutions would be to either make your entire content area a sortable handle or perhaps move your handles out to the left of the content (making that the 'sortable' area only) and drag only the handles (not the content), then allow the the content area to update upon a new sort.

Basically, it needs to be some how re-envisioned or designed to function properly.

Comment: Even when the entire cell is turned into a handle, it requires you to grab the row at either the very top or bottom of the cell to get it to work.  This is fairly unintuitive and feels like an oversight.

Comment: Yes, I agree. All the examples I see are of uniformly spaced handlers tho. That is def an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this very same problem. It seems like this only happens when there is no content or spacing beneath the jQuery Sortable list.

Just adding some spacing (e.g. `<div id="end-of-page-spacer" style="height: 500px;"></div>`) allowed me to drag large rows beneath smaller rows situated at the bottom of the list.